# The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to link a SQL Server instance A to other SQL Server
 Instance B through Linked Server with SQL Server Authentication, but I
 got below error.

I searched it again and again but failed to solve the
 issue...

[image]

Comment: Read exception information carefully. It is clearly said there that connection to your linked server can't be established. Ensure that server B is running listening for external connection and accessible from server A by network connection.

Comment: how to ensure that Server B is running for external connection....?

Comment: Google something like "sql server accept remote connections" - there are lot of articles about it, and there is no reason to write another one here in comments.

Comment: Can you connect directly to SQL Server B using that connection info (i.e. using object explorer). Are you absolutely certain you got the server/instance name correct?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yeah I used correct name of the Server/Instance

Comment: OK can you connect to that server directly from SQL Server Management Studio using that information? This is a SQL Server connectivity issue and there are about a million guides online for fixing this stuff. Here I googled one for you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/

Comment: Nick.McDermaid Thanks